# How in Eclipse/Gradle/Java project one can have different names for a project name and a root project directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Working with Eclipse/Gradle for Java projects I found that the root directory name should exactly correspond to the project name. Otherwise I am getting the error:

```
Could not get unknown property <projectName> for settings <directory-name> of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings
```

so cannot compile the Gradle project in Eclipse.  Other developers in our group work with IntelliJ, so they do not have this problem.  My workaround is to change the project name on my local but this is annoying working with git repository.  Is there any other workaround?

A permanent change in gradle files is OK if this does not ruin a build and gives the same resulting jar name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't explicitly set the root project name in `settings.gradle`, the project name will default to the folder name
2. If you don't explicitly set the eclipse project name in `build.gradle`, the eclipse project name will default to the Gradle project name

Eg: settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'foo'
```

Eg: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
eclipse.project.name = 'bar'
```

Comment: Yes, set eclipse.project.name = <folder name>, this solved the problem

Comment: It is better to use eclipse.project.name = project.rootDir.name , so that you don't have to hard-code eclipse.project.name.

Answer (score 0):

I think Eclipse does that by default. We can have any name for a project in eclipse. you can edit and change the name in .project file in your root folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, changing the project name in .project does not help, still getting the same error. I think that Eclipse Gradle looks at the directory name